# SQL Select to combine row values in output table using Pivot or CASE

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

I am using a PostgreSQL database and have a table as follows:

```
--------------------------------------
| Date  | MetricType  | MetricValue  |
--------------------------------------
| date1 | MetricA     | val          |
--------------------------------------
| date1 | MetricB     | val          |
--------------------------------------
| date1 | MetricC     | val          |
--------------------------------------
| date2 | MetricA     | val          |
--------------------------------------
| date2 | MetricB     | val          |
--------------------------------------
| date2 | MetricC     | val          |
--------------------------------------
```

As you can see, each date has a set of metric types and each type has a value. I want to write a Select statement which combines this data in the following manor

```
------------------------------------------
| Date  | MetricA  | MetricB  | MetricC  | 
------------------------------------------
| date1 | val      | val      | val      |
------------------------------------------
| date2 | val      | val      | val      |
------------------------------------------
```

I am not sure how to go about writing this Select statement to get these results. Can anyone help?

Comment: As *always* the question should include your version of PostgreSQL and an exact table definition. Consider the [info for the PostgreSQL tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql/info).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This data transformation is a *pivot*. If your database doesn't have a pivot function, then you can use an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression:

```
select Date,
  max(case when MetricType = 'MetricA' then MetricValue end) MetricA,
  max(case when MetricType = 'MetricB' then MetricValue end) MetricB,
  max(case when MetricType = 'MetricC' then MetricValue end) MetricC
from yourtable
group by Date
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/c0941/1)

The result is:

```
|  DATE | METRICA | METRICB | METRICC |
---------------------------------------
| date1 |     val |     val |     val |
| date2 |     val |     val |     val |
```

You can also do this using multiple joins on the table:

```
select a.date as Date,
 a.MetricValue as MetricA,
 b.MetricValue as MetricB,
 c.MetricValue as MetricC 
from yourtable a
left join yourtable b 
  on a.date = b.date and b.MetricType = 'MetricB'
left join yourtable c 
  on a.date = c.date and c.MetricType = 'MetricC'
where a.MetricType = 'MetricA'
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/73c1a/12)

Answer (score 3):

See http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#78

For a tutorial, what you are looking for is called a "pivot" This can also be done using CASE as shown here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241178/mysql-rows-to-columns

Answer (score 3):

Actually, Postgres **does** have pivot functions. Install the additional module [**tablefunc**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11750755/939860).
Find more details and explanation under this related question:
[PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query)

Your query could look like this. Assuming the metrics to be of data type `integer`:

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
   'SELECT date, metrictype, metricvalue 
    FROM   tbl
    ORDER  BY 1,2'  -- could also just be "ORDER BY 1" here

   ,$$VALUES ('MetricA'::text), ('MetricB'), ('MetricC')$$)
AS ct ("Section" text, "MetricA" int, "MetricB" int, "MetricC" int);
```

For simple queries a `CASE` statement [like demonstrated by @Bluefeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14367867/939860) will do. But this query performs *much* faster and is much shorter for longer lists of columns / bigger tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
    select a.date as Date,
     a.metric as MetricType ,
b.metric as MetricType ,
     c.metric as MetricType 
    from (select distinct date from yourtable where metric = 'metricA')  a
    join yourtable b on a.date = b.date and b.metric = 'metricB'
    join yourtable c on a.date = c.date and c.metric = 'metricC'
```